# What is your experience with using NASA's Core Flight System (cFS) in a subordinate system?

Tags: nasa, engineering

Has anyone used NASA's cFS on board a discrete system mounted on board an existing satellite/rover? What is your experience like? Have you encountered any difficulty forwarding TM/TC and managing systems internal to the subordinate system from the main platform?

Comment: Just letting you know, you are asking a question that many of those who could answer authoritatively cannot do so because of ITAR restrictions and/or nondisclosure agreements.

Comment: My admittedly very limited exposure to cFE/cFS was not positive. It felt like stepping back into the Stone Age. On the other hand, I work with people who are totally enamored with and even contribute to those tools. That said, they work with elements of cFE/cFS that are not publicly available due to ITAR restrictions.